# eBay API Grant Application Access return URL contains empty 'ebaytkn' parameter

Tags: sandbox, ebay-api

I need some help. When I click the "I agree" button on the "Grant Application Access Page" it returns to the predefined return url just fine which is `https://localhost/app/return`.

My problem is the query string that eBay sends to that return url

```
?ebaytkn=&tknexp=1970-01-01+00%3A00%3A00&username=testuser_USERNAME
```

The parameter `ebaytkn` is completely empty and I cannot understand whats causing this issue at all.

Someone help.

Thanks,

Grady

Comment: Possibly a sandbox issue, it wouldn't hurt to try this using a production account.

Comment: I have already tried on the production mode. Thanks

Comment: if I am following you correctly, this is not dynamic and based solely upon what you enter in your developer dashboard user tokens page for accepted and declined url parameters.  It's statically defined there and what I do is populate the url parameters based on what I want the app to see to indicate acceptance or rejection by the user.

Comment: @GradyPreece how did you solved that  ?

Answer (score 2):

If your eBay token return method is `FetchToken` (the recommended method), then this shouldn't matter. When you get to your accept page all you have to do is make a `FetchToken` call with the same `Session Id` that you used to generate the url. This is all documented in the eBay dev docs [here](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/HowTo/Tokens/GettingTokens.html).